# Regex for login page URL?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex, vb.net

Right now, I have this code:

```
string strURL = "aLogin.aspx?test=hello";
string strPattern = "(.*/)?Login.aspx(?.*)?";
bool bIsLoginPage = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(strURL , strPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I'm searching for the proper regexp pattern, and I am at a loss.

The pattern must fulfill these criteria

```
Login.aspx              ==> True
lOgIn.AsPx              ==> True
/Login.aspx             ==> True
whatever/Login.aspx     ==> True
whatever/lOgIn.aSpX     ==> True
WhAtEverLogin.aspx      ==> false
Login.aspxxxxxx         ==> false
Login.aspx?xyz=abc&etc  ==> true
Login.aspxxyz=abc&etc   ==> false
Login.aspx&xyz=abc&etc  ==> false
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Identify in a HTTP-module in a 3rd party web-portal whether the current URL is the login page. Then I save username + sessionID + datetime.

Comment: @Quandary, I hope this is for a specific case, and you aren't expecting every login page to have the word "Login" in the URL.

Comment: I'd suggest rather than using regex, you should use something like `HttpRequest.CurrentExecutionFilePath` and then use String functions to strip out the page name minus any QueryString values. Then it's just a case of comparing `yourstring.ToLower()` with "login".

Comment: @Brad: A very specific case, with .NET Framework 1.1. We need a safe way to pass the portal idendity to our own forms solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think about this?

```
^(.*[/])?login.aspx([?].*)?$
```

of course with ignorecase.

Answer (score 1):

Try `string strPattern = "(^|.*/)Login.aspx($|\\?.*)";` and `bResult = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(strURL , strPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

EDIT: Fixed missing escape sequence

Comment: Correction: "(^|.*/)Login.aspx($|\\?.*)"

Comment: Yes, sorry, usually prefix regex with @ for the string, got lazy with copy paste

Answer (score 1):

You can do without regex:

```
var target = "Login.aspx";
strURL.Split('?').First().Split('/').Last().Equals(target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Yes, true, that's how I wanted to do it. But first, an evil person can pass multiple question marks, and second, it can have a prefix, so you need endswith, and third, .NET 1.1 doesn't implement StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, and I don't want to spend much time on reinventing the wheel. I wouldn't bet on first and last being implemented either. Your variant boils down to string.contains with ordinalignorecase, and I really didn't want to implement that because.NET 1.1 doesn't support it, and second because string.contains is insecure in this case of usage.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you have to deal with .NET 1.1. Having multiple question marks is not really much of a problem if you check the sting length ahead of time, which you should probably do anyway. I know, First and Last are not available in .NET 2, so definitely not there for 1.1. Anyways, what's important is that you found a solution that works for you.